# JWT token no pide clave privada

Tags: php, jwt

estoy generando un token con php, con una clave privada y ese token se lo paso a otro sistema por url, y le paso la clave privada para que desencripte el token, pero no le pide la clave privada, quizá tenga u  error conceptual.
Así lo encripto:

```
  $privateKey = "sdasdas765asd76tasda7s";
                     $payload = array(
                            "iss" => "http://lapagina.com",
                            "aud" => "http://lapagina.com",
                            "user" => "josep",
                          "nombre" => "Jose",
                         "apellido" => "Perez",
                          "email" => "josep@gmail.com",                                                        
                            "iat" => 1356999524,
                            "nbf" => 1357000000
                    );
                    $token = JWT::encode($payload, $privateKey,'RS256');
```

y yo desencripto asi:

```
 $decoded = JWT::decode($token,$privateKey, array('RS256'));
```

Pero es necesario poner la clave privada para desencriptar? me dice quien lo desencripta que no, es mas, el token generado lo pego en jwt.io y lo desencripta perfectamente sin poner la clave privada en ningun lado, creo que tengo un error de concepto no? gracias

Answer (score 1):

Json Web Token, se estructura en tres partes. Header (metadatos del algoritmo), payload (tu mensaje json) y un hash. Puedes comprobarlo [aquí](https://jwt.io/).

Una función hash tiene una entrada y te devuelve una cadena de rango finitio y con longitud fija.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se modifica un sólo byte, la información cambia y ahí radica su seguridad.
JWT no deja de estar codificado en Base64, y lo puedes comprobar pegando tu Encode en esta [página](https://www.base64decode.org/). La clave privada la tiene el servidor, que prepara el token y lo envía al cliente, este lo guarda y lo reenvía al servidor.
Primero lo checkea, verifica y si es válido acpeta la petición.

**¡No sive para encriptar!**, si no para verificar la autenticidad del remitente.

Si quieres encriptar usa claves Pública/Privadas y algoritmos como SHA y RSA.

Para más información:
[OpenWebinars](https://openwebinars.net/blog/que-es-json-web-token-y-como-funciona/)

Infórmate sobre las buenas prácticas [API RESTFUL](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/buenas-practicas-para-el-diseno-de-una-api-restful-pragmatica/).

Comment: Concepto API REST:
Pides algo al servidor y lo autentificas con tu token
"modificame el título de mi perfil por este", aquí tienes mi DNI (token)
"borrame tal ajuste", aquí tienes mi DNI (token)
y etc etc.

Comment: Claro, muchas gracias, que librería podría usar para encriptar/desencriptar que sea algún standar para que se pueda desencriptar tanto php, javascript, c# etc. Muchas gracias

Comment: Ya es la librería con la que te sientas más cómodo.
Todos los lenguajes tienen un apartado de criptografía, por ejemplo
Microsoft [https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography?view=netcore-3.1](System.Security.Cryptography)
JavaScript [https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441](librerías)

Comment: Claro, pero que me asegura que si yo encripto con php una cadena con una librería, esa cadena en c# con otra libreria sea desencriptada con éxito, porque es obvio que la librería de php es diferente a la de microsoft